# Why List<> implements RemoveAll, but IList<> does not

Tags: c#, list

I'm refactoring my code to use IList instead of List. I used List.RemoveAll in a couple of places, and noticed that IList does not have this method at all. Is there any good reason for this?

Comment: Because the language designers agreed that not all types implementing `IList<T>` should have a `RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)` method.

Comment: because I = Interface, contain abstract methods you have to implement, see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't know the reason behind this interface design decision (probably trying to minimze the size of their interfaces?), but you can always write an extension method that covers you for any `IList<>`.

Comment: @AsfK: Could you write more concretely what that has to do with the question, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a principle in software engineering called [interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). It boils down to the notion that smaller interfaces are better than larger ones. When this idea is taken to the extreme, the ideal interface declares only one member - but let's not bother with that. The point is that interfaces should describe strict *requirements*, not *convenience* features.

In our specific case, the `IList<T>` interface declares the members that a type is required implement in order to be an `IList<T>`. Obviously, a type isn't required to implement `RemoveAll` in order to be an `IList`. It is *convenient* for a type to do so, but it's not required.

This is a valid use case for extension methods, though. You can define your own `RemoveAll` extension method for any `IList<T>` and keep the convenience.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the design principles. My question was more about this specific case - what can be a reason for System.Collections.Generic designers not to include RemoveAll in IList interface?

Comment: @SergeyKandaurov I would guess because they applied the above design principles for this specific case and figured that it's not a requirement they want to impose on people who implement these collections or a contract they want to maintain with the consumers of these collections. Keep in mind that `RemoveAll` can be implemented in terms of the already exposed members (without knowing its internals), so there's no reason to require the collection to implement it for you.

Comment: Makes sense now. Then I guess there should be some interface declaring RemoveAll for developer's convenience in order not to force using List<> or creating custom extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Although a general software design reason was explained by Theodoros Chatzigiannakis you might be interested in a solution when you do need a RemoveAll (maybe you received an IList from a library and want to manipulate that in an easier way). There is an answer here that might interest readers: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2199

Based on the answers from the Dotnet core team, I understand that the main reason is legacy, but as they said, you can easily write an extension method. An example of such an extension method (source:
https://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/icollection-t/removeall)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveAll<T>(this ICollection<T> @this, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        List<T> list = @this as List<T>;

        if (list != null)
        {
            list.RemoveAll(new Predicate<T>(predicate));
        }
        else
        {
            List<T> itemsToDelete = @this
                .Where(predicate)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var item in itemsToDelete)
            {
                @this.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```